# Get active vertex through python

Tags: python, scripting, vertices

I want to get the last selected vertex. I tried with `bm.select_history.active` but this don't work.

Comment: That should work, can you show a small example script that fails?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can walk the select history in reverse and find the first BMVert:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

for elem in reversed(bm.select_history):
    if isinstance(elem, bmesh.types.BMVert):
        print("Active vertex:", elem)
        break
```

Note that `select_history` does not support selection operators like box and lasso select. They don't make a geometry element active, nor do they add to the history at all.

Comment: Note that if this is to match the active vertex from Blender's perspective (all tools and draw code) - This should break after the first element.

Answer (score 8):

This function returns the active vertex,

*Note that if the last selected element isn't a vertex, Blender considers there to be no active vertex.*

```
import bpy
import bmesh


def bmesh_vert_active(bm):
    if bm.select_history:
        elem = bm.select_history[-1]
        if isinstance(elem, bmesh.types.BMVert):
            return elem
    return None


ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

print(bmesh_vert_active(bm))
```